# React Native: IOS app crashing at splash screen after successful build on iPhone 11 (IOS 15.0)

Tags: ios, react-native, build, ios15, xcode13

Recently I have updated my Xcode and its developer tools to 13.0 from 12.5. When I ran `react-native run-ios` after upgrade, I get an error asking me to upgrade from Legacy Build System to New Build System.

After upgrading I ran `react-native run-ios` again. The IOS app built successfully but when I click on the app in iPhone 11 (IOS 15.0), it shows splash screen for some micro seconds and then crashes. Here is the screenshot of the build system change I did

[image]

Screenshot of `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` message

[image]

Also, when I try to build from Xcode13, it builds successfully but shows following in output log

[image]

Please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you remove `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` folder and re-compile again?

Comment: Tried but do not work. Actually I solved it. The problem was we were running our own pre and post build scripts which were creating issues. Thanks but.